# VSCode Taskbar Icon - Shows a blank white file icon

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I open **VSCode** application on my Windows 10 Machine, the icon shows a blank white file in the taskbar instead of the **VSCode** icon. [(Preview)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuT5M.png)

I've looked online for a solution, and couldn't find an answer to my issue except for "Uninstalling Google Drive" which I do not have installed.

Actions done:

- Reinstalled **VSCode**.
- Rebuilt the C: drive icons.

Your help is needed, and thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through the Icon issue I had, I landed on this [website](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-rebuild-the-icon-cache-in-windows/).
I downloaded the cleariconcache.vbs file, and ran it - It worked for all the missing Icons on my Windows 10.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: This magical script works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Right Click the Paper White icon that should be a Visual Studio Code icon.
2. Right click on Visual Studio Code, then click Properties.
3. Change the Shortcut Target and Start in values to the same folder from where Visual Studio Code is installed.
4. Click Ok.
5. Close and reopen Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked on Windows 11 Pro 22H2:

1. Backed up my PC and files.
2. I download [this script from Leo Davidson](https://www.pretentiousname.com/miscsoft/#ClearIconCache).
3. Windows Defender automatically removed it. So I:

   1. Opened the **Settings** app > In the left menu, clicked on **Privacy & Security** > **Windows Security** > **Open Windows Security** > In the left menu, clicked on **Protection history**.
   2. There should be a blocked threat there. Click on it to open the link. Verify that the file path that was blocked is equal `<wherever you downloaded it>\ClearIconCache_1100_antivirusvendorsaretrash\ClearIconCache.exe`, in the bottom right corner there should be a button to **Recover** the file, click on it.
4. Open a terminal in the directory `<wherever you downloaded it>\ClearIconCache_1100_antivirusvendorsaretrash` by either:

   - Right mouse click in the directory and click on **More options** > **Open in Terminal**
   - You could also click in the address bar, type `cmd` and hit **Enter**
5. You can verify you are in the correct directory by running `pwd` and hitting enter. Whatever `Path` is returned should correspond with `<wherever you downloaded it>\ClearIconCache_1100_antivirusvendorsaretrash`
6. Now execute the script by running this command: `ClearIconCache.exe`. To prevent message-boxes telling you if the program succeeded or failed, run `ClearIconCache.exe /QUIET`. Don't worry, your explorer (desktop environment) will become invisible, show a solid color, and will return after some while.

**Your issue should now be fixed!**. Note that your context menu (the menu that opens when you right click some where in a folder) also has been reset, nice and clean.

## All credit goes to © 2019 Leo Davidson